# How to add graph widget using js in odoo8?

Tags: python, graph, widget, odoo

I am creating customer portal in odoo. In this portal I created different box widgets using JavaScript instance widgets in one page, and now I want to add graph widget into the page, anybody have idea how to add graph widget in odoo? I am attaching some snapshots below to understand it better.[image: this is graph]

[image: Graph widget should be here]

Comment: Did you got that widget ?

Comment: yes i got that one...

Comment: Can your share me the code. vigneshkrmmc@gmail.com